# Drawing a bunch of FBO seems slow

Tags: opengl

I'm rendering about 2000 objects on differents FBOs (one fbo per object).

At every frame I'm simply drawing a textured quad of each FBO into the "final" framebuffer (the window).
e.g. :

```
glBindFramebuffer(0);
loop_over_fbos {
    glBindTexture(fbo_texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     glVertex3f(...);
     ...
    glEnd();
}
```

This appears to be slow (20 fps for 2000 object) on a regular desktop computer.
Should I switch from direct mode to VBOs? Is it common to have so much FBOs? Can I achieve great performances with a lot a FBOs (e.g. 100k FBO)?

Comment: "*one fbo per object*" ***Why?*** What are you trying to do that you need to do this? Why don't you just render those objects to the screen?

Comment: If each of those FBO textures cover the entire screen, it seems reasonable that it's slow, since you're processing every single pixel of the entire screen for an object that perhaps only covers a few pixels, 2000 times over. You're probably bottlenecked at the ROPs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Long story short : I need every object to have their "own" memory. For instance, I can move the object on the screen without having to redraw what's behind.

Comment: @Dolda2000 No every object is something like 30x30.

Comment: "*For instance, I can move the object on the screen without having to redraw what's behind.*" You're redrawing the entire screen every frame anyway. "*No every object is something like 30x30*" Your objects are tiny; why bother drawing them to textures instead of just to the screen? They can't possibly take as long to render.

Comment: @NicolBolas Because I do not have the hand on the part that draws into the texture (read : my code doesn't know how the object was drawn). Also, every object can be post-processed with their own fragment shader.